# pessimistic update using ngrx entity

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

i have my actions setup like this

```
    export const bankAccountUpdating = createAction(
  '[Create New Account Component] Account Updating',
  props<{ update: Update<BankAccount> }>()
);

export const bankAccountUpdated = createAction(
  '[Bank Manager Effect] Account Updated',
  props<{ update: Update<BankAccount> }>()
);

export const updateAccountError = createAction(
  '[Bank Manager Effect] Update Accounts Error'
);
```

and the reducers are setup like this

```
 export const initialBankAccountsState = adapter.getInitialState({
  allBankAccountsLoaded: false,
});

export const bankManagerReducer = createReducer(
  initialBankAccountsState,

  on(BankManagerActions.bankAccountUpdated, (state, action) =>
    adapter.updateOne(action.update, state)
  ),
```

note that adapter.updateOne needs object of type Update from ngrx entity.

i have an effect setup that triggers on Updating and once server's response is returned i am trying to call "updated" action

```
 updateAccount$ = createEffect(
() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(BankManagerActions.bankAccountUpdating),
    concatMap((action) =>
      this.bankManagerHttpService
        .updateAccount(action.update.id, action.update.changes)
        .pipe(
          catchError((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            this.store.dispatch(BankManagerActions.updateAccountError());
            return of();
          })
        )
    ),
    map((account) => BankManagerActions.bankAccountUpdated({ account }))) //<--PROBLEM
   // ,{ dispatch: false }  );
```

problem is here when i am trying to call BankManagerActions.bankAccountUpdated it needs object of type Update so that it can call "updateOne" on adapter (in reducers) but at this point i dont have hold of action. how can i call BankManagerActions.bankAccountUpdated with Update object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your `map` operator inside `updateAccount` observable pipe:

```js
updateAccount$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(BankManagerActions.bankAccountUpdating),
    concatMap((action) =>
      this.bankManagerHttpService
        .updateAccount(action.update.id, action.update.changes)
        .pipe(
           map(account => BankManagerActions.bankAccountUpdated({update: {id: action.update.id, changes: account}})), // action here
           catchError((err) => {
            console.log(err);

            return of(BankManagerActions.updateAccountError());
          })
        )
    ),
);
```

I removed `{dispatch: false}` and `store.dispatch` as well.